# How to check whether pattern is matched by using preg_replace only

Tags: php, regex

Currently, I have the following code, which use to perform pattern matching & pattern replacing.

```
<?php

function fun($text) {
    if (preg_match("/^(ATE|EAT)\s+(\S+).*/", $text)) {
        $text = preg_replace("/^(ATE|EAT)\s+(\S+).*/", "EAT $2", $text);
    } else {
        $text = preg_replace("/.*(ATE|EAT).*/", "EAT", $text);
    }
    return $text;
}

// EAT pizza
echo fun('EAT pizza') . "\n";

// EAT pizza
echo fun('EAT pizza at paris') . "\n";

// EAT
echo fun('I EAT pizza at paris') . "\n";
```

I feel the above code is not optimized, as I'm performing `preg_match` before `preg_replace`. I feel this is redundant.

I tried to check the returned string from `preg_replace`

```
<?php

function fun($text) {
    $tmp = preg_replace("/^(ATE|EAT)\s+(\S+).*/", "EAT $2", $text);
    // I don't think this is the correct way to check for "Not Match" ?!
    if ($tmp === $text) {
        $tmp = preg_replace("/.*(ATE|EAT).*/", "EAT", $text);
    }
    return $tmp;
}

// EAT pizza
echo fun('EAT pizza') . "\n";

// EAT pizza
echo fun('EAT pizza at paris') . "\n";

// EAT
echo fun('I EAT pizza at paris') . "\n";
```

However, `fun('EAT pizza')` will fail, as it will print out `EAT` instead of expected `EAT pizza`.

Is there a correct way to optimize the above code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your function? If you always want the string to be "EAT pizza" then just set it to that if preg_match is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume all you actually ask for is to know how to know if there where any replacements in your preg_replace since it is quite unclear what you actually want to achieve.

From the PHP Documentation on [`preg-replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> **Description**
>
> mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
>
> [..]
>
> **count**
>
> If specified, this variable will be filled with the number of replacements done.

So if you add a *count* to your preg_replace, you'll get the number of replacements, thus the number of occurances.

Example given (*thou this is kind of into the blue due to lack of information*):

```
function fun($text) {
  $count = 0;
  $tmp = preg_replace("/^(ATE|EAT)\s+(\S+).*/", "EAT $2", $text, -1, $count);
  if ($count == 0) {
        $tmp = preg_replace("/.*(ATE|EAT).*/", "EAT", $text);
  }
  return $tmp;
}
```

So this will replace `ATE <something>` or `EAT <something>` with `EAT <something>`, or, if neither of those where found, it will attempt to replace `ATE` or `EAT` with `EAT`.

Comment: @Jonny5: That would still require two regex statements, thus not save any performance of prevent redundancy right? I probably could write an example, the only reason i didn't is because the question didn't provide information on what the function should actually do. There is no defined desired output for a given input example.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following function:

```
function fun($text) {
    $tmp = str_replace('ATE', 'EAT', $text);
    $pos = strpos($text, 'EAT');

    if ($pos < 0) {
        return $text;
    } else if ($pos > 0) {
        $tmp = preg_replace('/^.*?EAT/', 'EAT', $tmp);
    }

    $tmp = preg_replace("/^EAT\s+(\S+).*/", "EAT $2", $tmp);

    return $tmp;
}
```